# Php artisan can't make migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, server, laravel-artisan

Hi I have problem with make migration on my vps server with `php artisan migrate`.
I had installed apache2 and mysql.
I can connect to my database by `mysql -u root -p` with password 'pass#$'.
This is my env.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=**
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mysql
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pass#$

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

I have that informations from my database:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| laravel            |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

And this table info in mysql

```
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| engine_cost               |
| event                     |
| func                      |
| general_log               |
| gtid_executed             |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| innodb_index_stats        |
| innodb_table_stats        |
| ndb_binlog_index          |
| plugin                    |
| proc                      |
| procs_priv                |
| proxies_priv              |
| server_cost               |
| servers                   |
| slave_master_info         |
| slave_relay_log_info      |
| slave_worker_info         |
| slow_log                  |
| tables_priv               |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
| user                      |
+---------------------------+
```

What is more first i created my project on my pc and now I only get it from my github repository.
When I go to my webside ip i can see all my sites and views.

I tryied to change in .env file 127.0.0.1 to localhost, tryied to clear config by `php artisan config:clear` and  `php artisan cache:clear` but it stil don't works.

EDIT: I forgot

```
php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = mysql and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /home/projects/test/ArduinoWeather/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
      /home/projects/test/ArduinoWeather/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mysql", "root", "pass", [])
      /home/projects/test/ArduinoWeather/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: What is the error that you get from artisan output?

Comment: Have you tried putting your password in quotes? `DB_PASSWORD="pass#$"` Not sure how well DotEnv/Laravel handle those "special characters" in your password

Comment: Oh I didn't see this, thank you, now work

Answer (score 0):

make sure your mysql is running on port 3306 and your username and password is ok.
Then go to your project folder and

> config/database.php

change these :

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
```

and instead of using .env use static inline username and password like :

```
'usename' => 'root',
'password' => 'your password'
```

see if it works.